# How to fix JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString in iOS react-native-config and AsyncStorage?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-config

I'm having problems with react native config and AsyncStorage, where null data from .env is not readable on iOS,

below is my code:

```
  _authAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await syncStorageA.getItem(Config.ACCESS_TOKEN)
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth')
  }
```

Please help.

I'm having this problem only on the iOS platform on Android is working fine.

Comment: is Confi.accesstoken null in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you whenever you are setting the value to `SyncStorage/AsyncStorage` you are storing `null` value inside your storage. 
Rathe then storing it directly as in your case having chances of getting access token as `null`. check if the value exists or not.

might below snippet helps you

```
function set(key, value) {
  value = JSON.stringify(value)
  if (value) return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
  else console.log('not set, stringify failed:', key, value)
}
```

Comment: My problems is react-native-config did'nt get value from .env file.